# How can I implement today's popular keyword in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a function that tells the most searched keyword during the day?

How can you implement it if don't?

Answer (score 1):

The Elasticsearch search engine itself doesn't provide any analytics capabilities. However, the [App Search product](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/app-search/current) provides Analytics APIs on top of Elasticsearch, such as the [Top Queries API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/app-search/current/queries.html#queries-top-queries) which should return you what you need.

Comment: Actually, I migrated from App Search yesterday. :(

Comment: Well, there's no analytics API in ES, so you need to implement that yourself.